# Monitoring/logging a malfunctioning internet connection

Tags: windows, networking, internet, logging

I have a mysterious internet connection problem: Every 15-20 minutes, the connection will become very slow, and take 2-3 minutes for anything to load.

I've had a technician from the ISP over here to test the hardware, and everything is in pristine condition. They have no other explanation than a configuration error on my machine, a possibility I can exclude 90% because I'm experiencing the same problems with another machine.

I will have to monitor the situation now, and I would like to run a program that logs when internet connections become slow.

I thought about putting something together using `at` and `wget`. Does anybody know of some other tool for this that does this out of the box - maybe something with an adjustable request frequency, logging connection speeds etc.?

Comment: You could always keep a log of pings as well. Couldn't hurt.

Comment: @SpikeX good idea, especially seeing as pings seem to mysteriously work while the rest of the connection is down. Noted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that is a home environment and you don't have a server (or don't want) to run professional monitoring tools (even open source ones, like [zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/) and [nagios](http://www.nagios.org/)).

Give [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) a try. It's a nice tool. It's intended to do load/stress test, and I'm pretty sure that it can help you. At least you'll be able to see how your ISP responds to incrising levels of traffic.